# How to get the location of a standard assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-assembly, roslyn

I'm trying to feed Roslyn with the references stored in my .csproj file. This is simple if I have a local file, but I have problems adding references for "standard" assemblies like System etc. How do I do it (in Roslyn, MsBuild, or whatever)? Roslyn accepts references based on file paths, so i can't just add an assembly by name (that is, without loading it first). Or can I? If not, how do I find a path for an assembly listed in the project's references?

I know that the assemblies referenced there are not necessarily from GAC, that makes it even harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Test]
public void MsBuildPropertyContainsRefeerenceAssemblyFolder() {
    var project = new Project(@"D:\\Projects\\Chpokk\\src\\Chpokk.Tests\\Chpokk.Tests.csproj");
    var property = project.AllEvaluatedProperties.First(projectProperty => projectProperty.Name == "FrameworkPathOverride");
    Console.WriteLine(property.EvaluatedValue);
}
```

(you have to add `using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;` on the top)

Actually this is just one of the man folders to look, but the most obvious one. The complete list can be obtained via the `AssemblySearchPaths` property and includes folders found in Registry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Roslyn, but usual CSharp projects feed usual CSharp compiler (CSC.exe) with dll's from c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\ :

[image: building a sample solution]

I suggest you to try these reference assemblies (they are copied to your PC intentially for this purpose when you install VS )

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need -- I need to find it programmatically on a remote computer. Nevertheless, your answer pushedme in the right direction, so I upped it.